# null on System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session on OnActionExecuting asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5, iis-10, windows-server-2022

On local it accessible but after deploy it not work:

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["EflowSession"] return null

Comment: You will have to show more code (and context), as merely a call to a certain object can legally be `null`. And you are also using `HttpContext.Current` for no good reason (at least from the current question body). It is recommended to use `ControllerBase.HttpContext` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only on IIS, make sure that the `Session State` is not disabled for the application in IIS.

[image]